# What is the purpose of OpenFirmware interface

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

browsing the kernel source and looking at some drivers i found some methods and structures named with the prefix 'of' (for example struct of_device and the method of_phy_connect). I think that the prefix means OpenFirmware. In particular a driver i'm interested in (ucc_geth) uses those functions...what is the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

They're for enumerating/manipulating devices on systems that use OpenFirmware (New World Macs, OLPC XO systems, and more).